# 3px border automatically added when using border-style without specifying border size

Tags: css

I noticed that setting a border-style without specifying border size results in a border being added to your element.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Expected result:
There is no border around the box, because we have not specified the width of the border.

Actual result:
A black 3px border appears around the box.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lr7mt/

I guess my question is, why does this happen? Is it part of the W3C CSS specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand where the properties come from:

Regarding the color property, if unspecified this comes from the `border-color` property, which if not set takes the dominant value from each `border-*side*-color`, which if not set, reverts to the value for [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value), which is dictated by the value set for `color` which defaults to black.

**Color**

`border` -> no color set -> get from `border-color` -> no color set -> get from dominant `border-*side*-color`-> no sides set, revert to `currentColor`

The setting for width takes a similar route- but stops at the individual side width settings, which default to `medium`

**Width**

`border` -> no width set -> get from [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) -> no width set -> get from dominant [`border-*side*-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-width) (defaults to `medium`)

---

In summary, the default values are `black` and `medium`.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because border default width is medium :

```
border: solid medium black;
```

An example :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr7mt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is default border style, BUT the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-style) doesn't precisely define the thickness of each of the keywords (`thin`, `medium` and `thick`), which is therefore **implementation specific**.

Nevertheless, it requests that the thickness does follow the `thin` ≤ `medium` ≤ `thick` inequality and that the values are constant on a single document.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width).

Answer (score 0):

`border-style`, `border-width`, and `border-color` all have default ("initial") values, according to the spec:

- [border-style](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-style): Default style is 'none'
- [border-width](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-width): Default width is 'medium'
- [border-color](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#border-color): Default color is 'currentColor'

Obviously, when no border properties are specified, there is no border, because `border-style` defaults to 'none'. But as soon as you give a different `border-style`, such as 'solid', a border appears because width and color have non-zero and visible defaults, respectively. So all that is needed to get a border to appear is to set `border-style`.

---

Also, to comment on the previous answer (I don't have enough reputation to comment properly), it appears to me that the [specification does indeed define the thickness](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#typedef-line-width) of `thin`, `medium`, and `thick`, as "equivalent to 1px, 3px, and 5px, respectively."